# Would a comprehensive 'When should I negotiate and why' question benefit the workplace?

Tags: discussion

We get a number of questions like [this](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/19414/job-offer-after-internship) which basically boil down to the asker not knowing what to negotiate or when to negotiate it.

If we had a comprehensive question and answer that detailed *when* it's good to negotiate and *why* it's good to negotiate these things, would this be on topic and beneficial to workplace to point these types of users at?

Bad answers to this question:

> You should negotiate on the 25th of June
>
> You should negotiate 2 weeks after moving house

Good answers to this would be a long the line of:

> It's best to negotiate when you have a real need for something different to what you are being offered. For example if the pay they are offering you is below what you need to pay rent then it is best to negotiate this value.
>
> You should not try to negotiate just for the sake of wanting more, trying to get things you don't really need can come across as greedy, and negotiating for far more than you need can result in you not even getting considered

Of course these are just examples and I imagine that others can come up with additional points.

My question still stands: **Would a canonical Q&A of when and why you should negotiate help the workplace?**

If this is not fit for the main site, would having a question of that ilk be useful to have here on meta to point people to instead?

Comment: I'm not sure there is such a thing as a rule-based way to determine when to negotiate and when not to negotiate. Too many dependencies. It would be interesting to see a draft, but I'm having a hard time picturing one that would provide sufficient detail.

Comment: Hi @JoeStrazzere thats understandable, ill draft one up later today and post it as an answer here for an example if that would help

Comment: Many of the questions I've asked here have been questions which I wanted to make a more generic "reference" version of. I know a few others have done similarly and I think it benefits the site to have such "mini cannonical" questions. I frequently find myself referencing some of the ones I've asked to others asking related or even identical questions.

Comment: Would that make for a good blog post?

Comment: I was wondering the same thing @jmort253 , do you think that would be more beneficial than a Q&A combo?